# MS-DOS how to save a file opened with "edit"?

Tags: ms-dos

I'm trying to open a file from the command with this line: "edit file_name"

And I would like to save it after I have modified it.

Do you know the way to do this ?

Cheers

Comment: Try `edlin` instead.  ;-)

Comment: @Ok but how do you exit and save from within a edlin session ?

Comment: @mric750 Again, Google is your friend here, first hit gave me the answer on how to save in edlin, type `e` and press enter for End and Save. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/67706

Answer (score 11):

You press <kbd>ALT</kbd> key to activate the menu at the top of the screen, then use arrow keys or press <kbd>F</kbd> for the **F**ile menu, followed by <kbd>S</kbd> for **S**ave or <kbd>A</kbd> for Save **A**s

This information is easily available in the built in help system by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> or a quick Google search.

Reference: http://www.is.wayne.edu/DRBOWEN/InetF03/Edit/UsingDosEdit.htm

Comment: I forgot to say that I can only use the command line => no menu

Comment: You said the MS-DOS `edit` command, that runs the full screen text editor, are you using a different command?

Comment: @mric750 Command line programs can have menus too. Some even support mouse.

Comment: EDIT actually supported mouse, but for some reason not in CMD.

Comment: It supports mouse in CMD too, AFAIK. Perhaps you were using an older version @RayKoopa?

Comment: You need the *DOS mouse driver* installed. (Goes in Config.sys, generally as some form of LOAD statement.)

Windows 95/98 had a (somewhat flaky) pass-through for the Windows cursor that DOS programs using the mouse could use. 

Some versions require you to explicitly load a DOS mouse driver if you want one. I don't recall the permutations, but if you have no mouse in DOS, that's usually why.

EDIT *is* a fullscreen text editor that has useful menus and mouse support. It's not as good for your geek cred as EdLin, or VI, but that's only because it's actually worth using.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Well I don't recall exactly anymore, since it is a 16-bit tool and thus not shipped with 64-bit Windows which I'm using for years.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Yes but EDIT itself is a 16-bit program... now you actually make me try it.

Comment: @RayKoopa In order to get it to work you'll have to write a Kernel-mode assembly program to set up the processor before and after running NTVDM code.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm pretty sure you can't simply do that just out of thin air

Comment: @RayKoopa There's going to be quite a bit of undefined behaviour you can exploit in the chips, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You can't simply execute assembly code which switches the CPU mode under Windows.

Comment: @RayKoopa You can if you set up a Kernel-mode driver! :-) It's hard, but theoretically possible.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Yes of course it is possible with a driver, but you mentioned a simple "program" which is most commonly implicitly describing an executable ran without direct CPU access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45890/discussion-between-ray-koopa-and-wizzwizz4).